# Active Directory Domain name(s)

Tags: windows, active-directory, rdp

I've successfully created a test AD domain and joined several machines to it, for the purposes of this post I'll call the domain "TEST.COM". Everything seems to be working perfectly, except for one thing. When I use RDP to get access to one of the VMs in my domain, I can log in as either test1@TEST.COM **or** test1@TESD.COM. I have no idea what TESD.COM is or why I can access a machine on the VM I created with it.

Can anyone tell me why this might be happening or point me towards some tools I could use to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this only happened for test1@TEST.COM. I had somehow misconfigured the UPN of that user so that it was test1@TESD.COM. I changed it back and now things are working as expected.